# Vscode source control doesn't recognize my repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a local repo which was linked to a old remote repo. I made a new repo on GitHub and ran this in the folder

```
git remote set-url origin <new repo url>
```

where the url is the new repo. Then I ran

```
git push -u origin master
```

Which pushed everything to my new repo. If I run

```
git remote -v
```

I get the correct repo location. But vscode does not seem to recognize the repo. It is saying the folder currently open does not have a git repo. Why is this? I tried running git init which prints

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in <folder name/.git/>
```

But this doesn't do anything?

What can I do to make vscode's source control see my repo again? I have uncommited code, so not everything is pushed so I can't simply clone the repo.

**Edit:**

When I try to commit I get the following error

```
$ git commit -a -m "Renamed the repo"
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to go into my .git/config and update the worktree field to the new folder location.

Comment: I just close and open the Vs Code and start working again but it just put some files as untracked I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to run VS code as administrator (on Windows)