# VSCode doesn't detect that my git repo has been init

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I had to format my Windows 10 for some other problems, and when I tried to work with a repo which I have in another hdd, it seems like if it hadn't been init'ed by git, but I double-check and the git folder still is in this repo folder.

I can see all the project, I can run it, I can modify it, but it looks like git is not working on the repo.
If I click on source code control tab in VSCode, it shows me to init the repo or publish on GitHub.

Edit: In the project folder already exist .git folder, git for windows is installed and I open the project folder which contains .git folder on vscode.

I already installed the  GitHub extension, sign in from VSCode and also activated sync.
If I clone this repo to the desktop it works all fine as it has to, so I don't know if it can be something about hdd, some windows permissions or any other thing.

Just to clarify, it was working before formatting Windows, and I was using the same data hdd as I'm trying using now.
Thanks for helping me.

I already did a research but I can only find info about how to sync the GitHub account and all this stuff which is already done.
I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378649/vscode-source-control-doesnt-recognize-my-repo)
which seems to have similar problem but I can't find or I don't know where to update the worktree to my local folder.
If I clone the repo to my hdd where the old repo is, it still not working so I can't understand how it would fix it.

Comment: Is there a `.git` folder or a `git` folder in the project folder?

Comment: For me, the VSCode Git integration didn't work until I installed Git. Do you have Git installed?

Comment: Do you have the folder open (File->Open folder...)?